# Show disabled preferences in Mozilla Firefox 67.0

Tags: firefox, gentoo, default-settings

`about:preferences` shows

> Your organization has disabled the ability to change some preferences.

**How can I see what was disabled?**

I compiled Mozilla Firefox 67.0 from source (via ebuild on Gentoo Linux) on my personal computer and I did not disable anything by intention.

Answer (score 1):

Access `about:config`, sort by the "Status" column, and look for settings where status is 'locked'.

In particular, to determine the origin of those settings, look for `general.config.filename` which is the traditional Firefox autoconfig mechanism:

- https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customizing-firefox-using-autoconfig
- http://kb.mozillazine.org/Lock_Prefs

---

Recently Firefox gained a second, simpler mechanism – search for a file `policies.json` in your system; its contents will directly tell you what has been disabled:

- https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customizing-firefox-using-policiesjson

---

Finally, some preferences might have been disabled by add-ons you have installed. There's probably no central method for listing those.